# EF many-to-many relationship produces error only when foreign key properties are exposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I have the following many to many relationship defined with Entity Framework 6.1 code first attributes:

```
 public class Many1
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Join> Joins { get; set; }
}

public class Many2
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Join> Joins { get; set; }
}

public class Join
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ManyOneId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManyOneId")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Many1 Many1 { get; set; }

    public int ManyTwoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManyTwoId")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Many2 Many2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the foreign key properties are explicitly provided as well as their navigation properties. I can seed the database as follows:

```
 protected override void Seed(EfTestApp.Model1 context)
    {
        var one = new Many1 {Name = "one"};
        var two = new Many2 { Name = "two" };

        var join = new Join
        {
            Many1 = one,
            Many2 = two,
            Name = "join",
        };

        context.Joins.AddOrUpdate(j=>j.Name, join);

        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

This succeeds on the initial seed, but subsequent seed attemps fail with an EntityValidationError. However, if I comment out the foreign key properties and regenerate the migration, seeding works every time. This seems odd because, other than the naming differences, the migration file appears virtually identical between the two. Why do these produce different results?

Comment: what do you mean by subsequent seed?

Comment: Seed() is called each time additional migrations are added (or really, whenever Update-Database command is run). AddOrUpdate is designed to add the first time and update existing data subsequently.